Android Project Is Not Running - Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'
When I try to run the project, I encounter the following error, and despite trying multiple solutions, I haven't been able to resolve it:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/irozon/sneaker/sneaker/2.0.0/sneaker-2.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/irozon/sneaker/sneaker/2.0.0/sneaker-2.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/kaopiz/kprogresshud/1.2.0/kprogresshud-1.2.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/kaopiz/kprogresshud/1.2.0/kprogresshud-1.2.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/yarolegovich/discrete-scrollview/1.5.1/discrete-scrollview-1.5.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/yarolegovich/discrete-scrollview/1.5.1/discrete-scrollview-1.5.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
> Could not find com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/gdacciaro/iosdialog/1.0.3/iosdialog-1.0.3.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/gdacciaro/iosdialog/1.0.3/iosdialog-1.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

I have been trying to resolve an issue by changing the compileSdk, updating the compileOptions and kotlinOptions, and exploring various solutions available on Stack Overflow, but I still haven't found a solution that works. The project is running fine on my Team Leader's laptop, which is on macOS, but I'm working on Windows, and the issue seems to persist on my system. I would be very grateful if you could help me solve this problem.
build.gradle(Module:app) File
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter()
    }


    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.9'
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

build.gradle(Module:app) File
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hide.mytrack"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 19
        versionName "1.0.18"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_16
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }
    namespace 'com.hide.mytrack'
}


dependencies {

mplementation("androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.9.2")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'
    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kaopiz:kprogresshud:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.gdacciaro:iosdialog:1.0.3'
}

gradle.properties File
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME

settings.gradle File
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    }
}
rootProject.name = "MyTrack"
include ':app'


Just find those dependencies from jcenter() elsewhere.

The dependencies are available on GitHub. I checked for updates to the latest version, but they are already up-to-date. Also available on mvnrepository. What should i do next? Waiting for your positive response. Thanks
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.irozon.sneaker/sneaker
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gdacciaro/iosdialog
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yarolegovich/discrete-scrollview

Those libraries are no longer being maintained. Either move to something else that is maintained or fork them and maintain them yourself.
